# Can't access the elements of a Matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I'm new to python. Kindly don't go harsh on me if this question looks novice. I created a Matrix like this:

```
Matrix = np.matrix([[0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,1], [1,0,0,1], [1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1]])
```

Now, When I try to access the element of Matrix, like this:

```
import numpy as np    
print(Matrix[0][3])
```

I get the following error:

> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

I have been through all the related posts on stackoverflow but haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: Why search on SO instead of sticking to the [offical docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [slicing arrays in numpy/scipy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725750/slicing-arrays-in-numpy-scipy)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I'm trying to print the elements of a Matrix. I don't want to slice the Matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> Matrix = np.matrix([[0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,1], [1,0,0,1], [1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1]])
>>> print(Matrix[0,3])
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write comma separated indices

```
print(Matrix[0, 3])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.